# Questions method of the stackoverflow api returns only one page of questions

Tags: java, stackexchange-api

Trying to work with questions method of the stackoverflow api and it returns only one page of questions , how can I get the following pages?

The java code I am using :

```
URL stackoverflow = new URL("http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/"
                + method + "?" + "answers=" + includeAnswers + "&body="
                + includeBody + "&fromdate=" + fromUnixTime + "&todate="
                + toUnixTime);

        URLConnection connection = stackoverflow.openConnection();

        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says right in the [documentation for the questions method](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions) :

> page – The pagination offset for the
>   current collection. Affected by the
>   specified pagesize. 32-bit signed
>   integer